# How to select all records and format selected records in LINQ C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a Products table that contains around 100 columns. I would like to retrieve all columns and format some proxy columns like:
ApplicationType = i.ApplicationType.ToString(),
SystemOwnerDepartment = i.SystemOwnerDepartment.Acronym
how do I do that using LINQ. Here is the code that I have

```
var qry = from i in db.Products
                  select new
                  {
                      i.Id,
                       i.Name,
                      BusinessOwnerDepartment = i.BusinessOwnerDepartment.Acronym,
                      BusinessOwnerOffice = i.BusinessOwnerOffice.Acronym,
                      SystemOwnerDepartment = i.SystemOwnerDepartment.Acronym,
                      ApplicationType = i.ApplicationType.ToString(),
                      Status = i.IsActive.ToString()
                  };
```

Comment: And what is your problem with this code?

Comment: what's the problem with the code?

Comment: `I have a Products table that contains around 100 columns. I would like to retrieve all columns [...]`: do you mean a shortcut to create your 100+ properties object ?

Answer (score -1):

I see 2 options for you here.

1. create Source property, that will host initial object with all your columns, and create separate properties if needed:

   ```
           var qry = from i in db.Products
                             select new
                             {
                                 Source = i, // <-- this one
                                 BusinessOwnerDepartment = i.BusinessOwnerDepartment.Acronym,
                                 BusinessOwnerOffice = i.BusinessOwnerOffice.Acronym,
                                 SystemOwnerDepartment = i.SystemOwnerDepartment.Acronym,
                                 ApplicationType = i.ApplicationType.ToString(),
                                 Status = i.IsActive.ToString()
                             };
   ```
2. create display properties for your `Products` class that are going to return you formatted data
   Something like:

   `public string DisplayApplicationType { get { return this.ApplicationType.ToString(); } }`

You also can use `join` statement, but I'm not able to  create example query for you at the moment, so you can explore on it by yourself

Comment: I'm getting a circular reference exception for a proxy object: A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Department' I'm setting Proxycreating to false but still getting this error

Comment: @Indu527 you'll have to update you question with more details about your 
`Products` class in order to solve this

Comment: Following is a code snippet for my Product class.  [ForeignKey( "EngineOwnerDepartment" )]
        [Display( Name = "Engine Owner Department" )]
        [Required]
        public int? EnginesOwnerDepartmentId { get; set; }
        [Display( Name = "Engine Owner Department" )]
        public virtual Department EngineOwnerDepartment { get; set; } --Thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

The circular reference might be coming as you would be having a navigation property inside your Products objects which in return would be again referencing to some parent object. Please post your Product class structure.